# Load different menubars for PC vs Mac users

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

Each entry in the menubar for my app contains a shortcut key suggestion (e.g. Undo (CTRL+Z)). Is there an easy way to dynamically customize the suggestion string depending on whether the app is being used on a pc or on a mac?

thank you

f

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Capabilities.version](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/Capabilities.html#version) to get the version information.  The first three letters will tell you the host platform ("WIN", "MAC", or "LNX").  Use a string variable to store the text information ("Ctrl" or "Cmd") for your suggestion accordingly.

Comment: weltraumpirat, thank you for your answer. Will try it soon and report back.

Comment: awesome - finally gave it a try and all is well - thank you for your help!